# Twisted - Stop all Deferred in DeferredList

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I have a few task in **DeferredList** and sometimes worker can throw some error. How to stop all **Deferrs** in **DeferredList**? if something going wrong in worker

> ```
> def worker(word):
>     #can throw Exception
>     return word.upper()
>
> def worker_err(error):
>     #todo: stop all deffered in list
>     return 0
>
> def processing(words):
>     workers_list = []
>     for word in words:
>         workers_list.append(threads.deferToThread(worker, words).addErrback(worker_err))
>
>     return defer.DeferredList(workers_list)
>
>
> words = ['abc', 'test string', 'test']
>
> d = processing(words)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferreds are not running operations.  You can't stop a Deferred.  You may be able to use the `Deferred.cancel` API to try to stop the operation that is associated with a `Deferred` but this is an opt-in mechanism: the operation has to explicitly enable cancellation or `Deferred.cancel` won't actually stop the operation.

Threads in Python are not interruptable.  The `Deferred` returned from `deferToThread` therefore does not opt in to the cancellation mechanism.  You can't stop the underlying operation.

You can implement your own interruption mechanism for your worker function.  For example, you can share a `threading.Event` instance between the main thread and the worker function.  If you want the thread to stop, set the event.  In the worker function, check the event from time to time to see if it is set.  If so, abandon the job.